# DKIM syntax, DNS Server rejected

Tags: domain-name-system, email, dkim

I really need help on why my DNS host keeps on rejecting this entry:

```
default._domainkey.myschool.edu.sg IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfM...hZwIDAQAB;"
```

I added our domain based on what I have read so far. What cpanel gave is, which the server also rejects:

```
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfM...hZwIDAQAB;"
```

Now to test what's going on - it might be the key end of the entry, I tried doing this which the DNS host accepted:

```
myschool.edu.sg IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfM...hZwIDAQAB;"
```

Of course, that fails DKIM online tests.

I'm really lost. I followed everything I have found in the internet and it's been 2 nights since I tried anything new.

Comment: A) What is the error message you get? B) Have you tried to add closing `"` signs? They come in pairs...

Comment: Yes, the entries I posted above ends with: hZwIDAQAB;"

Comment: Then please edit your post to make this clear.

Comment: This is the error message: Error, the name default._domainkey.myschool.edu.sg contains invalid characters

Comment: I assume the given hostname is obfuscated? Can't find it in DNS.

Comment: I apologize for not giving the domain name. I have no authority to share it.

Comment: I have read 2 minutes ago that some DNS hosting service rejects the character underscore. I already emailed support and they told me the same DNS error message. If this were true - that their server cannot accept underscores - what should I tell them?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell your support engr to read the RFC.  That will keep them busy while you solve the problem yourself.  ;)

DNS RFC does not allow underscore in host names:
http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/names.html

But underscore certainly should be allowed in the subdomains.  Here is a blurb on it:
http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html

Back to your original issue...

How long is the key string?  (this: p=MIGfM...hZwIDAQAB;)

Each string is limited to 255 chars.  Though, you can define a single glob of data using multiple strings:
https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00356/0/Can-I-have-a-TXT-or-SPF-record-longer-than-255-characters.html

For a long string you will need to split it up (into multiple 32 byte strings) using syntax like this:

```
default._domainkey.myschool.edu.sg IN TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa;
                                            "p=MIGfM..................."
                                            ".........................."
                                            "....hZwIDAQAB;" )
```

Comment: It's 216 characters long.

Comment: I just got word from tech support and they said: We do not know anything about your infrastructure or what you
want to do.  All we know is that your hostname does not conform
to the standards. You can't have an underscore after a period.
You must choose a better hostname.  If you remove the period and the underscore, it will be a valid hostname.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the underscore from the dkim dns entry?

Comment: The "hostname" in your example is "default", and that does not contain underscores.  The "_domainkey" part is the "subdomain", and it is allowed to have underscores in it.  In fact, that is in the RFC:   [RFC4871](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt)   "3.6.2.1.  Namespace All DKIM keys are stored in a subdomain named "_domainkey"."

Comment: cpanel email authentication interface generated this: default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DK

Comment: i edited it to default._domainkey.myschool.edu.sg IN TXT "v=DK what I did is right?